# Semaphore array of type `sem_t`... Error

Tags: c, semaphore

In have declared the array as

```
pipesemid=shmget(9124,sizeof(sem_t)* 10,IPC_CREAT | 0666);
```

and initialised as

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    k=sem_init(&pipesem[i],1,1);
    fprintf(stderr,"%d ",pipesem[i]);
}
```

The value printed here is

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

but when is print it outside the loop it give an output of

```
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)‽

Comment: What are you doing with `pipesmid` and how is `pipesem` declared and initialized?